# Why are my Kick and ban commands Not working? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, syntax-error

I'm wondering why I keep getting an error from it.
Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def Kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'user {member} has been successfully kicked.')

@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def Ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been successfully banned.')
```

And here is the error:

```
 File "X:\Discord Bot\The Crew.py", line 82
    async def Kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Python 3.9.6

Comment: What's above the `Kick` command?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def Ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
await member.ban(reason=reason)
await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been successfully banned.')
```

Do Like This Instead

`@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)`
`@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)`